# How to make a node.js project in Google Drive Filestream

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, npm, flysystem-google-drive

I am trying to create a vue project on Google Drive Stream (windows10) but I cannot.

```
$ cd G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app
$ vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue sample-app
```

After this command, I input Enter to every questions from vue.
Then following error occurred.

```
vue-cli · Failed to write the file at: G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app\.eslintrc.js
EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app\'
```

I deleted G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app\ folder and tried again on powershell terminal running by administrator but the result is same.

I also tried to create a react project but similar error occurred.

````
$ create-react-app koseki-seiri-app

Creating a new React app in G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! path G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app\node_modules\.staging\@babel
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno -4075
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app\node_modules\.staging\@babel'
npm ERR! File exists: G:\MyDrive\webdata\sample-app\sample-app\node_modules\.staging\@babel
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rieko\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-26T21_54_16_969Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... node_modules
Done.```
````

How can I create?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that. ?? usually `node_modules` folder is very big and most binary files are dependent on the os and it could break on other systems. If you need to store the files online, one could make use some free tools like Github, gitlab, bitbucket to store the project privately.

Comment: @Panther Thank you for your advise. I decide to use Github.